# How do I add a new font of my choice into Visual Studio code?

Tags: html, css, fonts, visual-studio-code, font-family

I am fairly new at coding and I'm struggling with the following issue.
I have searched numerous times online on how to change the fonts in VScode to match the different fonts being used on a project of mine.

I've tried the suggestions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614605/how-to-use-custom-font-in-visual-studio-code) already but I still cannot see the fonts I selected and I cannot use them after going into "file > preferences > user settings" and overriding **"editor.font-family"**:

I have downloaded the following fonts on to my desktop already. Here are the fonts I would like to insert into the site I am working on.

- titilliumtext14l-600wt.otf
- OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
- OpenSans-Regular.ttf
- Myriad-Pro_31655.ttf

Here are the "Default Settings"

// Overwrite settings by placing them into your settings file.
// See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808995 for the most commonly used settings.
{

// Editor

```
// Controls the font family.
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",

// Controls the font weight.
"editor.fontWeight": "normal",

// Controls the font size in pixels.
"editor.fontSize": 14,
```

I'm not sure if it is necessary to include what I have in my "main.css" but here it is just in case.

```css
/** Fonts **/
@font-face {
    font-family: Titillium, Arial, sans-serif;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-thin-webfont.svg#gotham_thinregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Archivo Narrow, Arial, sans-serif;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../assets/fonts/gotham-black-webfont.svg#gotham_blackregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

/** Global **/
html, body{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    font-family: Titillium web, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-weight:light;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{
    font-family:latoregular;
}
h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #fff;
}
h2{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h2 span, h3 span{
    color:#ff8200;
}
h3{
    font-size:24px;
}
h4{
    font-size:18px;
}
h5{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:latoregular;
    font-weight:lighter;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
p{
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 2.0;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to change the font _of_? Of VS Code? Of a web page that you are developing _using_ VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

The settings that you changed are related to Visual Studio Code itself, you are changing Visual Studio Code's font.

To use a font for your website, you can add Google Fonts API into your header like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
```

Afterwards, go to your css file:

```
font-family: "Open Sans";
```

Answer (score 0):

First install the font on your machine if necessary. Then, in your user settings JSON file (*File > Preferences > User Settings*),  override `editor.fontFamily` like so:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "editor.fontFamily": "Source Code Pro"
}
```

You may need to restart VSCode if it was already open when the font was first installed.

Comment: I'll give it one more try to see if it works the second time I do that. Forgot to mention I tried that & it didn't do anything.