# How to use custom font in VSCode (yes, I've seen the other questions and User settings but it still won't work)

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

Okay, I've seen this: [How to use custom font in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614605/how-to-use-custom-font-in-visual-studio-code#)

And this https://superuser.com/questions/1296673/how-to-use-terminus-ttf-font-in-microsoft-visual-code-editor

and this: [How do I add a new font of my choice into Visual Studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982845/how-do-i-add-a-new-font-of-my-choice-into-visual-studio-code)

and this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12041

Etc etc etc.

This should be super simple, but it's not working and I don't know why.

I've got a font called Input. It's a monospace font for programming. I have installed it onto my Windows machine. I can see it available to use in Photoshop etc. But I can't get it to work with VScode and I don't know why.

I thought maybe it was because it was a ttf but I found that other link where the guy used escape characters for his TTF stuff and that didn't work either. So.... what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to code/preferences/settings and look for this line: "editor.fontFamily": "Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",

Change the font families to the ones you want. As a test I changed menlo to impact. When I saved the file it appeared all fonts changed to impact.

Comment: Yeah, I know. as I said, I've already tried that and it's not working and I don't know why. I was able to change it to default MS fonts but for some reason it's not loading any new fonts that I've installed. Do you have to exit and restart VScode to get it to work? I'm going to try again today and I'll post back if that's the issue.

Comment: i didn't have to restart but i had to save all.

Comment: I saved all also. But when I restarted it the next morning it did work so that's good

Answer (score 9):

Exatly same problem! No useful info in those answers/articles at all!

I have finally found out where the problem is: you need to **Install Microsoft Windows Fonts In Ubuntu**

simply do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then restart VS Code.

Comment: You are awesome, yes we have to install the font to the OS first.

Comment: Already installed, VS Code is still not able to recognize the font.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer, copy the .ttf files directly into `/usr/share/fonts`:

Here is the reference: https://amitpatel.xyz/how-to-install-jetbrains-mono-on-ubuntu-and-enable-in-sublime/

Comment: Cannot copy to `/usr/share/fonts` as copy permissions are not allowed in Ubuntu 20.04. So this answer does not work for me.