# Visual Studio Code - Os Sierra - font

Tags: macos, fonts, visual-studio-code

I have font "Menlo LG S Regular for Powerline" installed on my Mac OS Sierra, it has Unicode chars.
I need to setup this font in VS Code for Integrated/Internal terminal font in settings, but I don't know what font family name should I write?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add it as 'monospace' family, even 'sans-serif' family will work too, but monospace is more specific.

Comment: I have installed something like this: https://github.com/abertsch/Menlo-for-Powerline. In terminal I'm using "oh my zsh" with this font.

Comment: But in Visual Studio configuration file I don't know how to name this power line font.

Comment: As long as you install the font to the system, you should be able to use it for VS Code as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614605/how-to-use-custom-font-in-visual-studio-code.

Comment: Yeah, I get this in my confit file:
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Menlo for Powerline"
but terminal font is not good

Comment: If you have it in your file, make sure you have the font installed system-wide and restart VS Code. Possibly, you may need to restart your computer.

Comment: This is how it look in VS Code https://postimg.org/image/akx674za1/ 
It should look like this https://postimg.org/image/occj1fdcx/

Comment: Looks like the right font to me. The difference I see is a difference in how the font engine renders it. There's nothing you can do about that.