# How to add support for a custom non-unicode font in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, unicode, utf-8, fonts, text-editor

I have a custom [fantasy script](https://github.com/drumworkteam/tone) which looks like this (just the text portion):

[image]

It is a monospaced font built with FontForge. How can I add support for it to VSCode, so I can type in ASCII (like the left side [here](https://github.com/drumworkteam/tone/blob/build/HINT.txt)), and it outputs the random UTF-8 symbol mapped to the custom font in VSCode? So I can then save the file and have it be either a bunch of gobbledygook characters or the ASCII characters I originally typed?

Ideally this could be a plugin, so if you know of an open source VSCode plugin which I could use as inspiration, that would be a perfect answer as well.

I see how to [set a custom font in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614605/how-to-use-custom-font-in-visual-studio-code), but (a) that is globally, and (b) it doesn't necessarily solve the typing problem. I just really would like to know how to do this, not necessarily requiring an answer to implement it.

[Recommended UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/142328/ux-for-typing-editing-a-fantasy-script/142329#142329) is to have a "separate keyboard" for it, meaning typing the keys on the keyboard would result in different values. Maybe something like that can be done on a per-file basis?